# Suddenly gets android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

I have a little app that I made that have worked for months, but suddenly I get a

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I havent changed any code, this is the line that crashes

```
try {   
    endPoint = InetAddress.getByName(target.getToIp());
    port = target.getPort();
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
}
catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Note that I'm not sending anything I'm just creating the instances, it breaks already on the  InetAddress row.

It wored as late as last night, all I have done on the phone is run update on Google play, it updated to latest version of Google Maps, but that cant have anything todo with it?

It works in the emulator, only my HTC One X that breaks

Full code here
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/tree/master/Lib/Android/FreePIE%20Android%20IMU

edit:
Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.freepie.android.imu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">  

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Tried to move the problem code to the thread instead, now it wont break, but the socket is set to null.

```
running = true;
worker = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run(){
        try {   
            endPoint = InetAddress.getByName(target.getToIp());
            port = target.getPort();
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Exception err = e;
        }

        while(running) {
            try {
            sync.await();
            } catch(Exception e) {}

            Send();
        }
        try  {
            socket.disconnect();
        }
        catch(Exception e)  {}
    }
}); 
worker.start();
```

**update:**
Solution was to add some failback if user types a DNS instead of a IP
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/commit/e8017e02a7893d9df41e4ed67a037f016b6a7d39

Comment: please check internet permission in your manifest file.

Comment: Try putting your try-catch in AsyncTask.

Comment: Like I said, nothing changed in the source, same APK worked last night. Updated question with manifest, thanks for input

Comment: @Anders you have the same exception?

Comment: Nope, the catch does not hit, but the getByName never returns, it looks like the attach debugger is very confused right now. The code after sync.await does hit which means the code must return but the debugger cant cant cach it. When the sync await code does trigger the socket is null. But what happens between, no way of knowing this the debugger is FUBAR. The joys of workign with Eclipse/Java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on Android 4.0+ by default if you attempt to do network I/O on the  main application thread. `getByName()` does a DNS lookup if you provide a domain name (instead of dotted-IP notation), and that will trigger `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Why did it work on my 4.2 phone up to this point? If I move the code to the sender thread it the debugger does not even break when I get the exception, something strange is going on

Comment: @Anders: Perhaps `target.getToIp()` is now returning a domain name.

Comment: I moved the code to the sender thread, didnt help please see edit: Its a ip string btw

Comment: @Anders: Never write an empty `catch` block. Log your exceptions, and post a stack trace with what you are getting, along with the matching source code.

Comment: I agree with empty catch blocks, but Java is a crap language that enforce catch blocks. You should never  have catch blocks that you can't recover from. In this case if it were written in c# the program would crash and log the exception at a generic place. To polute the code with logging code is a anti pattern. But I agree empty catch blocks are bad. The problem still remains though :)

Comment: @Anders: "To polute the code with logging code is a anti pattern" -- not while you are asking for help, it's not.

Comment: The problem was a typo in the ip address (a space in beginning) thats why the DNS lookup tried to resolve the string that was now treated as a domain name instead of a address. Moved the code to the worker thread and the debugger went crazy and didnt want to break in the catch block. But logging in the catch did work and I could see the typo :P

Answer (score 1):

You must put your code in AsyncTask like this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
doInBackground(){
  endPoint = InetAddress.getByName(target.getToIp());
    port = target.getPort();
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
}
}.execute();
```

Note this code is not a working one, please read more about AsyncTasks [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Network on main thread is not allowed from the Android 4.0. If you run the code at Android 2.3 or other, it will not throw any exception.